# Cast const int pointer to int, in a switch case node

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, stm32

In my STM32 code i have an

```
#define USART1              ((USART_TypeDef *) USART1_BASE)
```

and i would like to have

```
switch((uint32_t)ptr)
{
  case USART1: return 1;
(...)
```

But gcc-arm (6.3.1) give me an error

> error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer

I found an information that i can use

```
  case __builtin_constant_p(USART1): return 0;
```

but this is only gcc solution? Is there something more generic?

Comment: What type is `ptr` ? What is `(USART_TypeDef *)` ?

Comment: switch(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>ptr)) ?

Comment: You are trying to cast a pointer to an integer -> `switch((uint32_t)ptr)`

Comment: @Unimportant In microcontroller environment like the CortexM3 (STM32) you find all hardware components described as a struct. The `USART_Typedef` is a typedef for the struct of the USART (a hardware component). `ptr`is obviously a pointer, since no other type is in question one can guess that's a pointer to anything like USART struct. -- Accessing the hardware using a pointer to struct makes sense when you work with a microcontroller.

Comment: @harper : But the macro is a (casted) pointer, and if ptr is also a pointer, then no cast is needed in the switch (or only a cast to the correct pointer type, but certainly not to integer), that's why I'm asking for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `UART1_BASE` which is just the sum of a couple of unsigned integer constants. See the machine header:

```
#define PERIPH_BASE           0x40000000U
#define APB2PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00010000U)
#define USART1_BASE           (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x1000U)
```

So should be able to use

```
switch((unsigned int)ptr) {
    case USART1_BASE: return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to cast pointer to integer in the case statement as well. 
Example from my working code:

```
switch ((uint32_t)gpio) {
    case (uint32_t)GPIOA:
        EXTI_cfgr = 0b0000;
        break;
    case (uint32_t)GPIOB:
        EXTI_cfgr = 0b0001;
        break;
    case (uint32_t)GPIOC:
        EXTI_cfgr = 0b0010;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

USART1_BASE is a number in the header files of the STM32 development environment. You can compile your code when you decided what type shall be used in the switch. I recommend `uint32_t`:

```
switch((uint32_t)ptr)
{
  case USART1_BASE: return 1;
  (...)
```

If you like more readability you can try to remove the cast from the switch:

```
uint32_t ptr_value = (uint32_t)ptr;

switch(ptr_value)
{
  case USART1_BASE: return 1;
  (...)
```